# How Can I Get the Tomboy System Tray Icon Back?

Tags: notification-area, tomboy

I'm running Linux Mint 17 with MATE, and while I have Tomboy (and can open it with no problem), it no longer adds a icon to the system tray when it's open. I also can't find an applet for it when I do "Add to Panel".

Can anyone please explain how I can get a system tray icon for Tomboy back?